# numpy dot product and matrix product

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm working with numpy arrays of shape (N,), (N,3) and (N,3,3) which represent sequences of scalars, vectors and matrices in 3D space. I have implemented pointwise dot product, matrix multiplication, and matrix/vector multiplication as follows:

```
def dot_product(v, w):
    return np.einsum('ij, ij -> i', v, w)

def matrix_vector_product(M, v):
    return np.einsum('ijk, ik -> ij', M, v)

def matrix_matrix_product(A, B):
    return np.einsum('ijk, ikl -> ijl', A, B)
```

As you can see I use einsum for lack of a better solution. To my surprise I was not able to use np.dot... which seems not suitable for this need. Is there a more numpythonic way to implement these function?

In particular it would be nice if the functions could work also on the shapes (3,) and (3,3) by broadcasting the first missing axis. I think I need ellipsis, but I don't quite understand how to achieve the result.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to generate the `'ij,ij...'` string based on the dimensions of the 2 inputs.  There is also a sublist method of specifying these indices.

Comment: What's the rule if `N=3`?  ie. two (3,3) arrays.  'ij,ij->i' or 'jk,ik->ij' or 'jk,kl->jl'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These operations cannot be reshaped into general BLAS calls and looping BLAS calls would be quite slow for arrays of this size. As such, einsum is likely optimal for this kind of operation.

Your functions can be generalized with ellipses as follows:

```
def dot_product(v, w):
    return np.einsum('...j,...j->...', v, w)

def matrix_vector_product(M, v):
    return np.einsum('...jk,...k->...j', M, v)

def matrix_matrix_product(A, B):
    return np.einsum('...jk,...kl->...jl', A, B)
```

Comment: And these work with `v=np.ones((3,))` and `A=np.ones((3,3))`.  There just isn't an obvious way of combining the 3 scenarios.

Comment: What seems strange, to me, is that in this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230296/numpy-row-order-in-the-representation-of-vector-funcions I was pointed to http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/ where it is proposed that a new operator '@' should be added to python to exactly perform the operations I need (if I understand it correctly). So it seems that numpy community is proposing a new python operator to perform an operation which at present is not performed by any dedicated function...

Comment: The Python community can add the `@` operator, but it will be the `numpy` developers who give it meaning for `ndarray`.  Whether it will include the kind of broadcasting that you want is an open question.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini The problem with generalizing matrix-matrix multiplication to higher dimensions is that there are two ways to do it. Numpy thinks of it as combinatorial inner products ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)) which is different than what you propose here.

Answer (score 2):

Just as working notes, these 3 calculations can also be written as:

```
np.einsum(A,[0,1,2],B,[0,2,3],[0,1,3])
np.einsum(M,[0,1,2],v,[0,2],[0,1]) 
np.einsum(w,[0,1],v,[0,1],[0])
```

Or with Ophion's generalization

```
np.einsum(A,[Ellipsis,1,2], B, ...)
```

It shouldn't be hard to generate the `[0,1,..]` lists based on the dimensions of the inputs arrays.

---

By focusing on generalizing the `einsum` expressions, I missed the fact that what you are trying to reproduce is `N` small dot products.

```
np.array([np.dot(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)])
```

It's worth keeping mind that `np.dot` uses fast compiled code, and focuses on calculations where the arrays are large.  Where as your problem is one of calculating many small dot products.

And without extra arguments that define axes, `np.dot` performs just 2 of the possible combinations, ones which can be expressed as:

```
np.einsum('i,i', v1, v2)
np.einsum('...ij,...jk->...ik', m1, m2)
```

An operator version of `dot` would face the same limitation - no extra parameters to specify how the axes are to be combined.

It may also be instructive to note what `tensordot` does to generalize `dot`:

```
def tensordot(a, b, axes=2):
    ....
    newshape_a = (-1, N2)
    ...
    newshape_b = (N2, -1)
    ....
    at = a.transpose(newaxes_a).reshape(newshape_a)
    bt = b.transpose(newaxes_b).reshape(newshape_b)
    res = dot(at, bt)
    return res.reshape(olda + oldb)
```

It can perform a `dot` with summation over several axes.  But after the transposing and reshaping is done, the calculation becomes the standard `dot` with 2d arrays.

---

This could have been flagged as a duplicate issue.  People have asking about doing multiple dot products for some time.

[Matrix vector multiplication along array axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170382/matrix-vector-multiplication-along-array-axes/18173082#18173082)
suggests using `numpy.core.umath_tests.matrix_multiply`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24174347/901925  equates:

```
matrix_multiply(matrices, vectors[..., None])
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', matrices, vectors)
```

The `C` documentation for `matrix_multiply` notes:

```
* This implements the function
* out[k, m, p] = sum_n { in1[k, m, n] * in2[k, n, p] }.
```

`inner1d` from the same directory does the same same for `(N,n)` vectors

```
inner1d(vector, vector)  
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', vector, vector)
# out[n] = sum_i { in1[n, i] * in2[n, i] }
```

Both are `UFunc`, and can handle broadcasting on the right most dimensions.  In `numpy/core/test/test_ufunc.py` these functions are used to exercise the `UFunc` mechanism.

```
matrix_multiply(np.ones((4,5,6,2,3)),np.ones((3,2)))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16704079/901925  adds that this kind of calculation can be done with `*` and sum, eg

```
(w*v).sum(-1)
(M*v[...,None]).sum(-1)
(A*B.swapaxes(...)).sum(-1)
```

---

On further testing, I think `inner1d` and `matrix_multiply` match your `dot` and `matrix-matrix` product cases, and the `matrix-vector` case if you add the `[...,None]`.  Looks like they are 2x faster than the `einsum` versions (on my machine and test arrays).

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/return-of-revenge-of-matmul-pep.rst
is the discussion of the `@` infix operator on `numpy`.  I think the `numpy` developers are less enthused about this PEP than the Python ones.

Comment: Nice explanation of why BLAS would be slow here. I am working on optimizing the `einsum` expression through the usage of intermediate tensors and BLAS calls. I wonder if this is a scenario we should consider. Check out the PR [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5488).

Comment: Last year while working on an `einsum` bug (involving Ellipsis) I wrote a pure Python simulator.  It may help in tracing the parsing of the index string.  Code is at https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum,